# Limit UITableView scroll speed like Instagram does it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to limit the scroll speed of my UITableView, exactly like Instagram does it.

If you check out Instagram, you'll notice that they have a limit on how fast you can scroll through the feed.

It's not set using "decelerationRate" since the limit doesn't affect the deceleration. It simply affects the how fast you can scroll through the feed. So if you try to do a "flick" gesture, you will hit Instagrams max scrolling speed and won't go as fast as in a normal UITableView.

Any guesses on how Instagram accomplishes this?

Comment: Why do you think Instagram is doing something special? I don't experience any scrolling speed limit when I try to reproduce.

Comment: @thelaws it most definitely scrolls slower somehow. When you scroll through the feed like you normally would and try and scroll through another feed in another app, then Instagram seems much more smooth.

Comment: Looks like it is very smooth, but not slow at all.

Comment: @k06a Smooth then... I would still say it's a little slower. But I guess the general feel you get, is that it's smooth. How do they do that?

Comment: I agree that it's not slowed down at all but I assume by 'smooth', you mean that there's no feeling of skipped frames while scrolling. If that's the case, then it's likely an issue of moving as much loading logic as you can to a background thread to allow the main thread to render as close to 60fps as possible. Instagram has a relatively simple table cell setup (one image, some text, couple of buttons). If you're getting a 'choppy' feeling while scrolling, I suggest doing a search for how to load images and other things in a background thread.

Comment: So did you get the answer?

Comment: No. Either they're not limiting the speed, otherwise I haven't been able to find out how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30771931/5395919 - Did this work?

Answer (score 15):

TableView has a property `scrollView`, This property will return internal scrollView of TableView. Use following...

```
tableview.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

ANOTHER WAY:

TableView will respond to scrollView delegate, so we need to implement scrollView's delegate like:

Take these global variables :

```
CGPoint lastOffset;
NSTimeInterval lastOffsetCapture;
BOOL isScrollingFast;
```

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll` like :

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {    
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeDiff = currentTime - lastOffsetCapture;
    if(timeDiff > 0.1) {
        CGFloat distance = currentOffset.y - lastOffset.y;
        //The multiply by 10, / 1000 isn't really necessary.......
        CGFloat scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000; //in pixels per millisecond

        CGFloat scrollSpeed = fabsf(scrollSpeedNotAbs);
        if (scrollSpeed > 0.5) {
            isScrollingFast = YES;
            NSLog(@"Fast");
        } else {
            isScrollingFast = NO;
            NSLog(@"Slow");
        }        

        lastOffset = currentOffset;
        lastOffsetCapture = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Then implement `scrollViewDidEndDragging` like this :

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if( !decelerate )
    {
        NSUInteger currentIndex = (NSUInteger)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width);

        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * currentIndex, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm quite sure it won't work though. "decelerationRate" just controls the deceleration, so that definitely won't work. Setting the point to scroll manually using an animation won't work either. The user don't have a feeling of decelerating when it's simply an animation. Any other options?

Comment: Try to look at instagram and try to flick the main feed and you'll see what I'm after.

Comment: Just try both options, I have used second option and it is working for me very fine. It would take just 5 minutes to try this option.

Comment: Can you post this in Swift. I am in an urgent need of the solution.

Comment: @NiravGadhiya scrollViewDidScroll only this method for fast scrolling ?

Comment: Your code at `scrollViewDidEndDragging` doesn't make sense, it's playing with the X axis while `scrollViewDidScroll` is playing with Y axis.

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
self.tableview.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

As tableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, ScrollView delegate will work here. Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit:**

if tableView doesn't show scrollView property use:

```
self.tableView.decelerationRate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "decelerationRate" simply controls the deceleration rate and has nothing to do with the general speed, so that won't work. Check out Instagram and try to flick the main feed and you'll see what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift set like this

```
tableView.decelerationRate =  UIScrollView.DecelerationRate(rawValue: 0.5)
```

[UIScrollView.DecelerationRate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/decelerationrate) having two rate types normal and fast. By default its normal (approx value >= 0.9). didn't check about fast value.

To do like Instagram you need to check velocity using `scrollViewWillEndDragging` method.

check velocity, if its above some threshold then set decelerationRate as per your need.